# In ActionScript, what character does "\t" represent?

Tags: actionscript, flash

In ActionScript, what character does "\t" represent? I can see it in some ActionScript And was wondering what character it really was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "tab space". `\n` and `\r` are other special characters that, in AS, represent new line characters (drops text down to next line, as if you were pressing the "enter" key in a text editor).

See http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=textcontrols_060_05.html for more.

Comment: Thanks! It was simple but I'm a newbie.